# How to solve one equation with two variables

Tags: python

I want to find the set of points (x,y) which satisfies equation

A((x-x0)^2)+2B(x-x0)(y-y0)+C((y-y0)^2)=deltachi2

with python. Here is my code

```
import math
deltachi2=2.3 #2.3 for 1-sigma and 6.18 for 2-sigma
A=3.
B=2.
C=1.1
x0=1.5
y0=3.
x_ini=1.
x_fin=2.
y_ini=2.
y_fin=4.
number_of_x_devisions=100
delta_x= float(x_fin-x_ini)/float(number_of_x_devisions)
number_of_y_devisions=100
delta_y= float(math.log10(y_fin)-math.log10(y_ini))/float(number_of_y_devisions)
filename="test.txt"
outfile=open(filename,"w") 

for i in range(number_of_x_devisions+1):
    x_i=x_ini+ i*delta_x

for j in range(number_of_y_devisions+1): 
    y_j=y_ini * pow(10,(delta_y*j))

    XX=A*pow((x_i-x0),2)+2.*B*(x_i-x0)*(y_j-y0)+C*pow((y_j-y0),2)
    if XX==deltachi2:
        outfile.write("%1.12e       %1.12e       %1.12e\n"%(x_i,y_j,XX))


outfile.close()
```

As I said, I need to find the set of points (x,y) which make the contour plots 1-sigma and 2-sigma (deltachi2 is 2.3 for 1-sigam and 6.18 for 2-sigma). However, the above code gives blank output. How can I find the contours correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your code above has an indentation problem; the `for j` loop should be nested inside the `for i` loop to do the sweep over two "dimensions".

In addition, since you're using floating point math (and with naive grid search instead of a better algorithm), you might not find the exact solution, so you'll need to use an epsilon, or accuracy threshold, to find the approximate solution.

In addition, I refactored your code a little to move the generation of the `x_i` and `y_j` values into generator functions, so the problem itself is easier to read.

```
import math


def x_gen(x_ini, x_fin, num_div):
    delta_x = float(x_fin - x_ini) / float(num_div)
    for i in range(num_div):
        yield x_ini + i * delta_x


def y_gen(y_ini, y_fin, num_div):
    delta_y = float(math.log10(y_fin) - math.log10(y_ini)) / float(num_div)
    for j in range(num_div + 1):
        yield y_ini * pow(10, (delta_y * j))


EPSILON = .01

deltachi2 = 2.3  # 2.3 for 1-sigma and 6.18 for 2-sigma
A = 3.
B = 2.
C = 1.1
x0 = 1.5
y0 = 3.

for x_i in x_gen(1, 2, 100):
    for y_j in y_gen(2, 4, 100):
        XX = (
            A * pow((x_i - x0), 2)
            + 2. * B * (x_i - x0) * (y_j - y0)
            + C * pow((y_j - y0), 2)
        )
        err = abs(XX - deltachi2)
        if err < EPSILON:
            print((x_i, y_j, XX, err))
```

This code prints out a couple possible solutions (I added printing out the error too):

```
(1.0, 2.411615655381521, 2.307584439928287, 0.007584439928287168)
(1.01, 2.394957409237857, 2.3088676681935825, 0.008867668193582645)
(1.02, 2.378414230005442, 2.3096504347952513, 0.009650434795251517)
(1.03, 2.3619853228590606, 2.309936594096949, 0.009936594096949136)
(1.04, 2.3456698984637576, 2.309730056780758, 0.009730056780758112)
(1.05, 2.3294671729369116, 2.309034788099698, 0.009034788099698154)
(1.06, 2.3133763678105748, 2.3078548061624873, 0.00785480616248746)
(1.07, 2.29739670999407, 2.3061941802500714, 0.006194180250071568)
(1.08, 2.2815274317368472, 2.3040570291634124, 0.004057029163412551)
(1.09, 2.265767770591597, 2.3014475196020174, 0.0014475196020176107)
(1.1, 2.250116969377619, 2.298369864572757, 0.0016301354272427737)
(1.11, 2.23457427614444, 2.2948283218284615, 0.0051716781715382965)
(1.12, 2.21913894413569, 2.290827192335828, 0.009172807664171945)
(1.18, 2.1140360811227605, 2.304659088270414, 0.00465908827041428)
(1.19, 2.0994333672461347, 2.2971249106473923, 0.002875089352607496)
(1.23, 2.027918959580058, 2.307983227711846, 0.00798322771184612)
(1.24, 2.0139111001134378, 2.2979409062094645, 0.0020590937905353712)
(1.77, 3.9723699817481437, 2.3089132998333692, 0.008913299833369415)
(1.8, 3.9176811903477073, 2.2975700722470327, 0.0024299277529671315)
(1.88, 3.784230586902383, 2.301749866868204, 0.0017498668682041085)
(1.9100000000000001, 3.7321319661472296, 2.2946153619215264, 0.005384638078473447)
(1.99, 3.6050018504433208, 2.3087335898127352, 0.00873358981273542)
```

Comment: Thanks. When I decrease the value of epsilon (to 0.001 or 0.0001) in order to increase accuracy, the output will be blank. Is there any way to increase the accuracy? And as an another question, what happen if I write XX<=deltachi2 in if clause instead of XX==deltachi2? In this case the output is not blank, but I do not have the border of contours. Is it correct?

Comment: The output is blank in those cases unless you also include the number of divisions to check with the naive grid search that's currently implemented, as there are no results with that resolution that would satisfy the epsilon requirement. If you need an exact result, you may want to look into symbolic math libraries for Python, or if you just want a more exact (but still not fully exact) result, use a root-finding algorithm like Newton's or something.